# How to implement product listing in Dot NETNUKE

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

I want to implement product listing in Dot NETNUKE 
tell me steps to implement this.

Comment: Follow this steps : http://kevalgangani.blogspot.in/2015/04/make-page-dynamic-in-dnn.html

Answer (score 0):

The fastest / most efficient way to do it is with a generic data module like 2sxc, which allows you to create content-types (with title, details, packshot, description, brand, etc.), list-views and details views. Your question is extremely generic though, so it's not easy to give a more detailed answer.

My recommendation is to start with an existing, similar open-source implementation and go from there - I would recommend the employee directory app http://2sxc.org/en/Apps/Details?AppGuid=ce646ddd-8789-4fef-8f39-b7e1d1908fe3

Alternative tools to do something similar are xmod or the very old list-and-forms